# Allocating and initializing object in one function, sending it to other function and release it there

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I Have this function that allocating and initializing object :

```
    +(Item*)getItem:(NSString*)uid{
         Item *file = [[Item alloc]init];
         //do some stuff
         return file;
    }
```

and this is the call for this function:

```
    Item *tmp = [LibraryScan getItem:itemid];
    //do some stuff
    [tmp release];
```

Now i want to release it after i get it,like i write above.
Have I done it right?

Comment: Any particular reason not to do it using an autorelease pool instead?

Comment: There is any reason why to do it with this way?

Comment: Only if you _really_ have the need to handle memory manually for some special algorithm that uses a lot of memory. Otherwise, autorelease is definitely the way to go.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my opinion, you should autorelease the object before returning it, letting the caller decide if he wants ownership on it :

```
+(Item*)getItem:(NSString*)uid{
     Item *file = [[Item alloc]init];
     //do some stuff
     return [file autorelease];
}
```

So :

```
Item *tmp = [LibraryScan getItem:itemid];
//do some stuff
//[tmp release]; nothing to release
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes your code is correct. But it also should meet the objective-c naming conventions that state that methods returning non-autoreleased objects (that is - the object that caller is responsible to release) should contain copy, alloc or new in method name.

So I would change your method name to `newItem` if you really want to return non-autoreleased object from it.

Comment: Do you have any example how to do it in your way?

Comment: He means the name of the method should be, according to naming conventions:

+(Item*)getNewItem:(NSString*)uid
+(Item*)allocItem:(NSString*)uid

Or something like that.

Comment: @MTA, it will be exactly like your code, but +getItem method name changed to +newItem.

Answer (score 0):

Its not wrong but its not a standard way.

Modify your implementation by this:

```
+(Item*)getItem:(NSString*)uid {
     Item *file = [[[Item alloc]init]autorelease];
     //do some stuff
     return file;
}
```

and :

```
Item *tmp = [[LibraryScan getItem:itemid]retain];
//do some stuff
[tmp release];
```

It will help you to debug the memory leaks properly.